# Can't find 3rd error in stroustrup's PPP2e chapter 7 drill

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble finding the third error in Stroustrup's http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator08buggy.cpp

So far I've added this in struct Token to get the code to compile:

```
Token(char ch, string s) :kind(ch), name(s) { }
```

And in Token_stream::get I've changed

```
while(cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch))) s=ch;
```

to:

```
while(cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch))) s+=ch;
```

and this:

```
if (s == "quit") return Token(name);
```

to:

```
if (s == "quit") return Token(quit);
```

but I can't find the last error. I can't seem to get the code to break and after re-reading the code several times I couldn't find any more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int i = ...` // signed vs. unsigned comparsion (use size_t instead)

`i <= names.size()` // it'll access element after last valid one later

And also unused variable on line 139

Token::get(), double get_value(std::string) and double primary(): at least one path without return...

Comment: just wondering but how long did it take you to find these errors? i guess i need more experience/practice

Comment: I've used -Wall for most of these.  And  `<=` is really common mistake, so it was like a lighthouse in the dark for me - I've just saw it on first sight.